# Unload Event : Distinguishing Page Closing from Refresh/Reload for ending session

Tags: javascript, angular

How to differentiate a page closing from page refresh/reload inside page unload event.

I have a situation where I want to end session of user by sending a logout request inside the unload event. But I don't want to trigger this in case of page reload or refresh.

I tried to do this by setting flag in sessionStorage, but I couldn't find a way to figure out if it's a refresh or reload inside unload event. So, sessionStorage is of no use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.